# Vim Color Schemes in Putty Step by Step process

Tags: vim, putty

How can I make `Vim Color Schemes` in `Putty`. I started working with `Putty` recently, and I was thinking is there any way to make that happen? Can anyone provide me step by step process how to do it? I saw various articles on the internet, but was not able to figure it out the step by step process.

Comment: When you say "make Vim colorscheme in Putty" what exactly do you mena? Vim colorscheme is a textual file defining color values used for the highlighting categories in Vim. What has putty got to do with it? You can use anything to edit the file really.

Comment: What I am looking for is- Is there any way to get VIM color like schemes in Putty? When I opened Putty I always get only single color thing, but when you work with with VIM we have different different colors schemes

Comment: Ah, so you're asking whether Putty has any support for colors? Have you tried reading the first few google:"putty colors" hits? http://www.igvita.com/2008/04/14/custom-putty-color-themes/ http://www.darkrune.org/blog/?p=213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable 256 colors in PuTTY go to Window->Colours->Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode. Of course, the server will also have its `$TERM` set to `xterm-256color` and your vim will need to be using a 256 colorscheme.